# Restore SSH key during install on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, ssh, raspberrypi

So I am doing a lot of testing with fresh installs.  I am reinstalling the OS a lot to the SD card on the raspberry pi.  One problem I am running into is when I reinstall use the same name for the machine I have to remove the SSH key on my client machine to log into the newly installed machine.  I then restore the key manually on the reinstalled machine, and then remove the key again on the client and reconnect.  Is there a better way to handle this?  It is annoying I can't or don't know how to supply a private SSH key during install.

Some more background this is on a Raspberry PI 4, it is headless.  I am just adding the ssh file to the boot folder to enable ssh on first boot.  I know how to restore manually by copying the private key into the .ssh folder, but am looking for a way to automate this on an install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a industry standard solution for virtual and bare metal provisioning of machines called 'cloud-init' which allows a YAML file configuration file to be used to configure linux when it first boots.

https://cloud-init.io

However Raspberry PI OS doesn't have cloud-init enabled out of the box so there is a GitHub project which provides a RPIOS Lite image which does.
https://github.com/timebertt/pi-cloud-init

However Ubuntu for RPI does support it in its preinstalled images..

All you have todo is copy your yaml file to the boot partition of the SD card and when it boots it will auto configure.  You can configure pretty much anything users, network, creates files and services..

Example of a user-data file which creates a custom user with a pre-installed public key.

```
#cloud-config

hostname: raspberry-0
# update /etc/hosts according to hostname (otherwise sudo will complain)
manage_etc_hosts: true
locale: en_US.UTF-8
timezone: Europe/London

users:
- default # pi user
- name: tim
  gecos: Tim Ebert
  groups: sudo
  sudo: "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
  # set to false to allow password login for this user
  # only for verifying with dockerpi, passwd auth over SSH should be disabled
  lock_passwd: false
  shell: /bin/bash
  # salt + hashed password, generate with `mkpasswd` or `openssl passwd -6`
  passwd: $6$U3.pM4pSkWuWC/AV$c/GZctLhbySMEKPF2wIgMrQB4jM7lPToi4oFlI9b53XSvcT/C8KM.HYnsQdXJI9ICmqXbVOwIhzovXk8JAbMc1
  ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa 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
  - ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJsGtuJYWgCwGHznLg8A2Iqm124z4vvoZmC0cIwr1D6V

# # authorized ssh keys for default user (pi)
# ssh_authorized_keys:
# - ssh-rsa AAAA...

# set to true to allow ssh password authentication (disabled by default)
ssh_pwauth: false
```

Well worth learning this solution..